# Find System.gc() in compiled libraries

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I see explicit gc invocations in our gc-log (see below). I am able to remove invocations with -XX:+DisableExplicitGC but I really want to know which code/library is calling `System.gc()`?

Any hints on how to track it down?

```
2011-05-30T12:21:48.230+0200: 1.672: [Full GC (System) 1.672: [CMS: 0K->2227K(2868864K), 0.0862299 secs] 62069K->2227K(3118080K), [CMS Perm : 12899K->12893K(409600K)], 0.0863197 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.03, real=0.09 secs]
```

Comment: I'd just start the application in a debugger and put a method breakpoint on `System.gc()` (and `Runtime.gc()` just to be sure).

Comment: Debug was a really good and easy suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom version of the System class which writes to a file a stack trace whenever System.gc() is called. This will allow you to trace all the places it is called.

This will find calls anywhere in the system including the JDK.

One place you get calls to System.gc() is in the RMI module to help find discarded remote objects.  You can decrease how often it will call a full GC with

```
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=86400000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=86400000
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net). It's a fabulous tool, and it have a built-in rule for explicit Garbage COllection calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use profilers. Any of the modern profiler would help you find this.