# What is the best way to trace who is calling System.gc

Tags: java, garbage-collection, byte-buddy

Is there a way to track down a System.gc caller without having to edit and recompile a class from the JDK? Something with Reflection (proxies) or with [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/#/)? By the way, I'd need Java 8 and Java 17 ways (if they are different)

Note:
I've come across these posts: [How can I tell who calls System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870829/how-can-i-tell-who-calls-system-gc) and [How do I replace Runtime.gc() with my own implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957951/how-do-i-replace-runtime-gc-with-my-own-implementation?noredirect=1&lq=1) , but they suggest we should change some jdk code and recompile, well I think maybe there is a better way to do that.

Comment: If that method is consistently called the simplest way to find the caller is probably to just start your application in the debugger and put a breakpoint in/on that method. This way you'll catch it no matter if it's called directly or via generated code.

Comment: Agreed, but that is not the case. That happened just one time after months running.

Comment: Debugging is out of question, as System.gc is not consistently called, it was a one off event.

Comment: Are you directly or indirectly using Java RMI? It periodically calls System.gc(), based on some special criteria. If you connect to the application using JMX, it will activate the Java RMI system.

Comment: @boneill I've checked that already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to attach a Java agent with a MemberSubstitution in Byte Buddy. You can use it to replace the call to System.gc to another static method that records the call instead of triggering the garbage collection, for example by writing down the stack trace.

You'd use an AgentBuilder to create the agent and apply the substitution to all types and methods if you have no idea from where the call is coming.

In theory, you could instrument the method itself but since it is native, it is not that straight forward, making the substitution the easiest option.

Comment: I'll try that. As you said, the downside of this is that a direct call to Runtime.getRuntime().gc() wouldn't be intercepted, but I originally asked about System.gc anyway.
Thanks

Comment: I think, ordinary code shouldn’t contain a call to `System.gc()` to begin with. From that perspective, it’s weird to replace calls to `System.gc()` with a logging call, to [wait up to a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76661983/what-is-the-best-way-to-trace-who-is-calling-system-gc#comment135160821_76661983) for the call to happen, when you could immediately report the fact that the code contains such a call. In other words, maybe the OP asked the wrong question.

Comment: It's probably in some library which would be also instrumented. Not always easy to predict the call stacks.